# Why starting for loop at i=1 giving me segmentation fault in this vector problem?

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector

I am trying to create a variable sized array which will help me store values and will allow me to retrieve and print the value as query asks. I actually completed this problem but as I am new to coding part, I just wanted to ask why using for loop starting from i=1 to i<=n gives me segmentation fault?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    int n, n1, data, q1, q2, q; /*n is number of variable length arrays and q is queries*/
    cin>>n>>q;
    vector< vector<int> > a(n); //vector as suited for to take input in number of arrays required
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        cin>>n1; //number of element in first array index
        for(int j=1;j<=n1;j++)
        {
            cin>>data;
            a[i].push_back(data);
        }
    }
    for(int i=1;i<=q;i++)
    {
        cin>>q1>>q2; /*taking input queries as array index and then inside that second query pointing to variable array elements*/
        cout<<a[q1][q2]<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: because vector allocates  from [0...n-1], your loop should run (i < n OR i <=n-1)

Comment: Because all indices start at 0

Comment: Starting it at 1 isn't the problem. Ending it at `n` is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you declare a `vector` like this:

```
vector< vector<int> > a(n);
```

it has size `n`. Indexing in c++ (and in fact, most programming languages), starts from `0` and goes to `n-1`.

If you index into a `vector` of size `n` with the index `n` (as you are doing in your for loop), this is an out of bounds index, and invokes undefined behavior. The result of undefined behavior is that the program can do *anything*. A segmentation fault is actually a good result, since you can fix the bug before anything too unpleasant happens.

You can also try indexing into a vector with `.at()`. This is also wrong, but it's a different kind of wrong; it's defined behavior, and it's defined to throw a `std::out_of_range` exception telling you exactly what you did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When you first declared the vector, you gave it `n` elements, which are from `0` to `n - 1`. However, in your for loop, `i` can reach upto `n`, which causes a segmentation fault (or vector subscript out of range) when you try to modify `a[i]`, since it doesn't exist yet.